# Basic analysis of large CSV with FF package in R

Tags: r

I have been messing around with R for the last year and now want to get a little deeper. I want to learn more about the `ff` and `big data` packages because have been trouble getting through some of the documentation.

I like to learn by doing, so lets say I have a huge CSV called data.csv and its 300 mbs. It has 5 headers Url, PR, tweets, likes, age. I want to deduplicate the list based on URLs. Then I want to plot PR and likes on a scatter plot to see if there is any correlation. How would I go about doing that basic analysis?

I always get confused with the chunking of the big data processes and how you cant load everything in at once.

What are come common problems you have ran into using the ff package or big data?
Is there another package that works better?

Basically any information to get started using a lot of data in R would be useful.

Thanks!

Nico

Comment: This is quite an interesting (set of) questions, and any answers you get will no doubt be useful to others. But unless you bulk out your question with a bit more specific detail, you probably wont get any good answers. You should edit your Q to include the output from `head(dput(data))` and a sample of the desired output. For your (3) have a bit of a search for `colClasses` and try this http://rforwork.info/2012/10/11/know-your-dataset-ffdf/ to exclude certain cols from being read in. You might also look into the `sqldf` and `filehash` packages.

Comment: Thanks, your right! After reading it again I can see how it looks confusing. I am going to rephrase it.

Comment: @NicoM ff documentation is a mess